# Set different background on hover to each unique id with a loop

Tags: jquery, wordpress, loops

I am doing a Wordpress test project where I have an overview page for some other projects. When I hover over a project, the body get's a background related to the project.

I wrote a loop adding an unique id of #project-number to each project dynamically. For simplicity, I wrote the ID's myself in the code below. Now I would like to add a loop that adds the hover support for every project I add. The problem is that they will all need another hover image. Otherwise I would have to add some jQuery with every project I add.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column12 project-overview" id="project-1">
    <h2>Project 1</h2>
    <p>Type of project - date</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column12 project-overview" id="project-2">
    <h2>Project 2</h2>
    <p>Type of project - date</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column12 project-overview" id="project-3">
    <h2 class="test">Project 3</h2>
    <p>Type of project - date</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column12 project-overview" id="project-4">
    <h2 class="test">Project 4</h2>
    <p>Type of project - date</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: rgba(199, 178, 153, 0.1);
}
```

jQuery

```
var body = $('body');
$(function(){
  $('#project-1').hover(function(){
    body.css('background', 'url(http://placehold.it/1920x1080/6699FF) center top fixed');
    body.css('background-size', 'cover');
  }).mouseleave(function(){
    body.css('background', 'rgba(199, 178, 153, 0.1)');
  });
});
$(function(){
  $('#project-2').hover(function(){
    body.css('background', 'url(http://placehold.it/1920x1080/00FF00) center top fixed');
    body.css('background-size', 'cover');
  }).mouseleave(function(){
    body.css('background', 'rgba(199, 178, 153, 0.1)');
  });
});
$(function(){
  $('#project-3').hover(function(){
    body.css('background', 'url(http://placehold.it/1920x1080/FFFF00) center top fixed');
    body.css('background-size', 'cover');
  }).mouseleave(function(){
    body.css('background', 'rgba(199, 178, 153, 0.1)');
  });
});
$(function(){
  $('#project-4').hover(function(){
    body.css('background', 'url(http://placehold.it/1920x1080/0000FF) center top fixed');
    body.css('background-size', 'cover');
  }).mouseleave(function(){
    body.css('background', 'rgba(199, 178, 153, 0.1)');
  });
});
```

I made pen, which is available here http://codepen.io/linkerd/pen/BsanI .
Would really appreciate some help. I tried several options, but none seemed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define image url to element's data attribute which will be replaced on body with mouse over:

[**Here is demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JLfFA**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JLfFA)

html:

```
<div class="column12 project-overview" data-bg="http://placehold.it/1920x1080/6699FF">
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  var body = $('body');
  $('.project-overview').hover(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('data-bg');
    body.css('background', 'url('+ target +') center top fixed');
    body.css('background-size', 'cover');
  }, function(){
    body.css('background', 'rgba(199, 178, 153, 0.1)');
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is more or less the same as the code provided by Satpal? Liking this solution very much, seems to work fine. I will define a custom post field in my plugin like Gerald Schneider suggested somewhere here. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: i'm glad to help you mate, btw you don't need to define document ready each function which you create, you just wrap your functions with one document ready, they will all work. here is a demo which i prepare for you @linkerd http://jsfiddle.net/mqy7w6m3/

Answer (score 4):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var body = $('body');
  $('.row').hover(function() {
    body.css({
      'background': 'url(' + $(this).data('bgimage') + ') center top fixed',
      'background-size': 'cover'
    });
  }, function() {
    body.css('background', 'rgba(199, 178, 153, 0.1)');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: rgba(199, 178, 153, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" data-bgimage="http://placehold.it/1920x1080/6699FF">
  <div class="column12 project-overview" id="project-1">
    <h2>Project 1</h2>

    <p>Type of project - date</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" data-bgimage="http://placehold.it/1920x1080/00FF00">
  <div class="column12 project-overview" id="project-2">
    <h2>Project 2</h2>

    <p>Type of project - date</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" data-bgimage="http://placehold.it/1920x1080/FFFF00">
  <div class="column12 project-overview" id="project-3">
    <h2 class="test">Project 3</h2>

    <p>Type of project - date</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use custom `data-*` attributes to store image to be displayed on hover.

*HTML*

```
<div class="row" data-bgimage="http://placehold.it/1920x1080/6699FF">
</div>
```

*Script*

```
var body = $('body');
$('.row').hover(function () {
    body.css({
        'background': 'url(' + $(this).data('bgimage')+ ') center top fixed',
        'background-size': 'cover'
    });
}, function () {
    body.css('background', 'rgba(199, 178, 153, 0.1)');
});
```

Comment: This is the most practical approach (if you don't want to update your css and js files every time you add a new pfoject). Just store the values per project in custom fields directly in the post.

Comment: Yeah, this is better than keeping an array.

Comment: Indeed, a nice and simple solution. Much appreciated!